# Perl script replace syntax

Tags: perl

Below is my Perl script

```
str_replace(rtrim(c_manager),'''','_'),'."\n".
 throws error  

str_replace(rtrim(c_manager), '''"
```

Bad name after _' at pl_recert_output.pl line 262.

Please help to solve this issue:

```
$sql = 'select rtrim(f_admin_disabled),'."\n".
                '       convert(varchar,t_password,101),'."\n".
                '       rtrim(c_email),'."\n".
                '       str_replace(rtrim(c_manager),'''','_'),'."\n".
                '       rtrim(c_mgr_email)'."\n".
                '  from tuserprofile'."\n".
                ' where ic_user1 = '."'$user_id'"."\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

You have single quotes within your single quoted string.

Single quotes within a quote string must be escaped with `\'`.

However, you would be better off using the [multi-line quoting syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for cleaner code:

```
$sql = <<EOF;
select rtrim(f_admin_disabled),
       convert(varchar,t_password,101),
       rtrim(c_email),
       str_replace(rtrim(c_manager),'''','_'),
       rtrim(c_mgr_email)
    from tuserprofile
    where ic_user1 = '$user_id'
EOF
;
```

This has the intended result without messy escaping and string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the single quotes in your variable assignment:

```
my $user_id = 'test';
my $sql = 'select rtrim(f_admin_disabled),'."\n".
            '       convert(varchar,t_password,101),'."\n".
            '       rtrim(c_email),'."\n".
            '       str_replace(rtrim(c_manager),\'\'\'\',\'_\'),'."\n".
            '       rtrim(c_mgr_email)'."\n".
            '  from tuserprofile'."\n".
            ' where ic_user1 = '."'$user_id'"."\n";

print $sql;
```

results in :

```
   select rtrim(f_admin_disabled),
   convert(varchar,t_password,101),
   rtrim(c_email),
   str_replace(rtrim(c_manager),'''','_'),
   rtrim(c_mgr_email)
   from tuserprofile
   where ic_user1 = 'test'
```

Check if that is the result you expected.

Comment: Canot skip the sinle quoted variable arugument...throws error Incorrect syntax near 'Leary'. (SQL-42000) [state was 42000 now HY000] [MERANT][ODBC Sybase ASE driver][SQL Server]Unclosed quote before the character string '      help for another solution

Comment: What if you just write last line as:  ' where ic_user1 = '.$user_id."\n"; You can print the output from your perl program run on your DB and tweak your variable assignment so that it remains a valid perl script and emits correct DB query.

Comment: str_replace(rtrim(c_manager),\'\'\'\',\'_\'),'."\n" these lines throws the same error canot skip the single quoted variable arugument..... ex :in the c_manager column values are 'S'achin' inside the single quotes variable name replaces script ie.,S_achin as i want.....help